# Methods in swift with a return type

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I have been trying to convert Objective C code to swift, I have been fairly good up until now, I have come across a method and a return type to that method which I haven't dealt with before in swift.

```
updateHUD = [(GameObjectNode *)other collisionWithPlayer:_player];
```

I have got `GameObjectNode().collisionWithPlayer(_player)` but still missing `other` and I dont know where it goes.

Comment: please read the swift book and understand what casting is / how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
updateHUD = (other as GameObjectNode).collisionWithPlayer(_player)
```

In the original Objective-C code, `(GameObjectNode *)` was casting `other` to that type before calling the method `collisionWithPlayer`. You were creating a new instance of `GameObjectNode`.

Comment: You're welcome. Even though you're learning Swift, I suggest picking up a good book on Objective-C like the one from the Big Nerd Ranch since all of us devs will be living with Objective-C code for years to come.

Comment: Definitely, I learned Objective C pretty well with a Big Nerd Ranch book, will do the same with Swift, thanks